# Printer cannot scan to network shared folder - Error msg. "Selected servers are not found"

Tags: networking, printing, scanning, printers

The scan operation for the printer was normal since 1 year ago, however since last month, scanning to network shared folder is not working and the printer was popping up this error:

> Selected Servers are not found. Consult your network administrator.

I tried the following:

- I ping from printer to file server and vise versa, and its successful.
- I tried to scan to email address, and its successful.
- i disabled the firewall and i tried the scan, and its not scanning.
- i uninstalled any recent updates, and still its not working
- the server workstation group policy didn't change!

Nothing recently has been applied to the print server and i don't know What could be the reason behind this failure.

Any advice or further troubleshooting suggestions ?

thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

SMB was upgraded past v.1.  There may or may not be a firmware upgrade for your Sharp MFP (depending on the model) to correct the problem.  Other than that, the scanner is telling you that the destination currently doesn't exist, or there was changed authentication that was not updated in the MFP's address book.

Answer (score 0):

I just figured out the reason behind that scanning process failure. After the installation of this windows security updates (KB3161949), i failed to scan to that server.

Once uninstalled, every thing works normally.

Hope that will help someone !